Oauth2 flow rejected by Google when running in Zoho Widget
I am trying to implement an extension in the Zoho CRMs widget framework that leverages some Google APIs. I can't seem to get the OAuth flow to work, I have followed the Google implementation of OAuth for server to server, but for some reason the user is never redirected to the oauth2callback and receives the response "403. That’s an error. We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know." However, when I paste the initial authorization url into a browser, the program executes as expected with no issues. Anybody have any idea how to get the oauth flow correctly working, or why it is not working as expected.
require('dotenv').config()
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
var https = require('https');
var chalk = require('chalk');

const { google } = require('googleapis');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const url = require('url');
const session = require('express-session')

process.env.PWD = process.env.PWD || process.cwd();


const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://localhost:5000/oauth2callback';
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  REDIRECT_URI
);

const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
];

var expressApp = express();
var port = 5000;

expressApp.set('port', port);
expressApp.use(morgan('dev'));
expressApp.use(bodyParser.json());
expressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
expressApp.use(errorHandler());


expressApp.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

expressApp.get('/plugin-manifest.json', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('plugin-manifest.json');
});

expressApp.use('/app', express.static('app'));
expressApp.use('/app', serveIndex('app'));


expressApp.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const state = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
  // req.session.state = state;
  res.redirect('/app');
});

expressApp.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: scopes,
    // Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
    include_granted_scopes: true,
  });
  console.log("redirecting to: ", authorizationUrl)
  res.redirect(authorizationUrl);
});

expressApp.get('/oauth2callback', async (req, res) => {
  console.log("here")
  let q = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

    if (q.error) {
      console.log('Error:' + q.error);
    }
    else {
      let { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(q.code);
      oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

      /** Save credential to the global variable in case access token was refreshed.
        * ACTION ITEM: In a production app, you likely want to save the refresh token
        *              in a secure persistent database instead. */
      userCredential = tokens;

      // Example of using Google Drive API to list filenames in user's Drive.
      const drive = google.drive('v3');
      drive.files.list({
        auth: oauth2Client,
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
      }, (err1, res1) => {
        if (err1) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err1);
        const files = res1.data.files;
        if (files.length) {
          console.log('Files:');
          files.map((file) => {
            console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
          });
        } else {
          console.log('No files found.');
        }
      });
    }
    res.redirect("https://127.0.0.1:5000")
})

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, expressApp).listen(port, function () {
  console.log(chalk.green('Zet running at ht' + 'tps://127.0.0.1:' + port));
  console.log(chalk.bold.cyan("Note: Please enable the host (https://127.0.0.1:" + port + ") in a new tab and authorize the connection by clicking Advanced->Proceed to 127.0.0.1 (unsafe)."));
}).on('error', function (err) {
  if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
    console.log(chalk.bold.red(port + " port is already in use"));
  }
});

